# Access linear layout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I am beginners in android. I am using ndk application. I have touchpad class and extends Linearlayout. also I have use this type of xml file. This xml file can't access. I got exception below. How to access this xml files and that class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<org.android.TouchpadLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/touchpad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/dreamote_btn"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@+drawable/keyboard" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="48dip"
            android:src="@drawable/gmote_touch_flat"
            android:tint="#99000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

</org.android.TouchpadLayout>
```

based on this class

```
public class TouchpadLayout extends LinearLayout {
  public TouchpadLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    return new BaseInputConnection(this, false) {
      @Override
      public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        return super.sendKeyEvent(event);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean performEditorAction(int actionCode) {
        sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
        return super.performEditorAction(actionCode);
      }
    };
  }

}
```

Get Exception on :
[image]

Comment: what's the package name of the class TouchpadLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing this - xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android and check once?

xmlns stands for xml namespace. in your case you are setting namespace to android namespace

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the namespace for your class.  See an example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) from google.